# Custom mail verification template in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I want to customize the default laravel email verification message with a custom html template, I tried different solution but either working only in laravel 5 or the verification button is not working,
I followed this tutorial : 
https://medium.com/@pran.81/how-to-implement-laravels-must-verify-email-feature-in-the-api-registration-b531608ecb99

My verify method :

```
    public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $userID = $request['id'];
    $user = User::findOrFail($userID);
    $date = date("Y-m-d g:i:s");
    $user->email_verified_at = $date; // to enable the “email_verified_at field of that user be a current time stamp by mimicing the must verify email feature
    $user->save();
    return response()->json("Email verified!");
}
```

The verification notification class:

```
class VerifyApiEmail extends VerifyEmailBase{

protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
{
    return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'verificationapi.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
    ); // this will basically mimic the email endpoint with get request

}}
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/verification#verification-views?

Comment: I did, but the resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php file is for email verification page , I want to customize the template in the email message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish the notification and mail resources:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

And Edit resources/views/notifications/email.blade.php with your custom template

Answer (score 0):

In previous version Laravel 6.0 after make:auth you will see email template at `resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php`
With Laravel 6.0
From changelog

*The frontend scaffolding typically provided with previous releases of Laravel has been extracted into a laravel/ui Composer package.*

So firstly install laravel ui and ui:install

```
composer require laravel/ui  "^1.2" --dev
php artisan ui:auth
```

Comment: I did, but the resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php file is for email verification page , I want to customize the template in the email message